# How to put form next to img?

Tags: html, css

I want to do the following:

IMG INPUT TEXT INPUT TEXT SUBMIT

and it all centered, so I cant use simply the floating. All I have:

```
<img src="lws_img.gif" />
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="1" name="1" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="2" name="2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In addition, all input texts+button has to be as heighted as the image.

Comment: You added the CSS tag, are you using any CSS?

Answer (score 1):

use this:

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/Bq9Ej/)

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <img src="lws_img.gif" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="1" name="1" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="2" name="2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form{ text-align:center }
form img, form input{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Vtvr6/)

CSS:

```
.centerIt { text-align:center; } 
img,form,input { display:inline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:table` is also a solution

demo : **http://jsfiddle.net/sS8HB/3/**  Top Aligned

demo2 : **http://jsfiddle.net/sS8HB/4/** Center aligned

**css**

```
.master{
    display:table;
}
.img,.frm{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top; /* for top aligned */
    /*vertical-align:middle; /* for middle aligned */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="master">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="frm">
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="1" name="1" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="2" name="2" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
```